# Google Earth Map Labels vs Placemark Labels

Tags: kml, google-earth

I would like to add labels to my GE map with pop-up info balloons containing info that is relevant to the entire map without tying that information to any particular point on the map. I can create a placemark with a description, but that nails the label to an arbitrary geographic point.

I would prefer to nail the label to a point on the screen, so when the user zooms or pans, the label stays on-screen but out of the way (say, lower right corner). The closest I have come is to create a placemark and set its visibility=0 or delete its coordinates. That gets the placemark name as a link in the Places panel, and it provides the pop-up info behavior, but the label is not shown on the map at all.

For examples, see https://sites.google.com/site/tuobikes/kml/gloryholetest.kmz

or https://sites.google.com/site/tuobikes/kml/gloryholetest2.kmz

Click the Read This! or Help placemarks in the Places panel.

Can this be done? I haven't found anything addressing this anywhere--any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider using a [screenOverlay](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_screen_overlay)

See [this page for an example](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/customcontrols/index.html) of using a screenOverlay as a button which opens a message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The scripting to create the information pop-up is beyond my means right now, but the screenOverlay has the screen behavior I'm looking for. Unfortunately the GE on-screen hyperlink relationship between a Placemark and its description isn't implemented for a screenOverlay (the image on-screen is not a link to the description.) I understand the idea is to be able to place and image on the screen. I'm not sure what the downside of implementing that relationship for screenOverlay would be. Your answer helps and gives me ideas.